# find multiple MAX values with IN clause and WHERE condition

Tags: sql, database, oracle, group-by

Given a simple table:

```
ColumnWhereIn    ColumnWhere    ColumnSearched
A                   1234                1
A                   1234                2
B                   1234                3
B                   1234                4
C                   1234                5
C                   1234                6
```

I would like to find the greatest `ColumnSearched` value. So the expected result is:

```
{A: 2, B: 4, C: 6}
```

I tried the following query:

```
SELECT mt.ColumnSearched AS cs, mt.ColumnWhereIn AS cwi FROM MyTable mt
 WHERE (mt.ColumnSearched, mt.ColumnWhereIn) IN
 (SELECT MAX(ColumnSearched), ColumnWhereIn FROM MyTable
 WHERE ColumnWhere = 1234
AND ColumnWhereIn IN ('A', 'B', 'C')
GROUP BY ColumnWhereIn)
```

But it is not returning any records.
Obviously I could just run three selects like this:

```
SELECT MAX(ColumnSearched) FROM MyTable
WHERE ColumnWhere = 1234 AND ColumnWhereIn = 'A'
```

But I was wondering if there's a cleaner solution.

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, your subquery produces those exact results...

Comment: Thanks... that was so obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `ColumnWhereIn` to SELECT and GROUP BY clause:

```sql
SELECT ColumnWhereIn, MAX(ColumnSearched) AS MaxColumnSearched
FROM MyTable
WHERE ColumnWhere = 1234
GROUP BY ColumnWhereIn
```